# Todo list type of app for Windows AND Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, note-taking

I need some recommendations on a good todo list type of app that works on Windows and Ubuntu. I would like to keep track of my assignment's due dates across both OS.

I used to use Windows Sticky Notes before I started dual booting with Ubuntu. Now I need a replacement. Doesn't have to be fancy. Just need text, but easy to access and preferably in my face so that I don't forget.

Comment: Can you be more specific? A local app, or is online OK too? Which ones have you tried that don't fill your needs? There are already [lots of questions on todo-apps on this site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=todo), use these to find an answer or to sharpen your requirements here if you can't find what you want. [And read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: I second Jan's request for more details. If web-based is "technically OK" for you, you might also want to consider privacy. There're nice and powerful solutions like the one [presented by har00n86](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11745/185) – but you might pay it revealing private data. You still could setup your own stuff for this, e.g. using [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/), which ships with Todo, calendar, contact lists, and much more.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have found something that covers exactly what I was looking for. I have updated the OP if you are interested. @Izzy I'm only using this to keep track of school assignments, so I have no issues with privacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the suggestions. I ended up using a free open source app that is available on Ubuntu and Windows called Tasque. It can be found here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tasque

The app can store the list locally or via Remember the Milk's API (which is what I decided to use). It's simple and exactly what I was looking for. It says open in the taskbar area of Windows and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

You would be well advised to take a look at [RedNotebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/) - it is available for multiple systems and is very flexible:

- OS = Windows, Linux & Mac
- Free (Gratis + FLOSS)
- [Portable Apps](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/rednotebook_portable) Version
- Plain Text storage rather than DB
- Can include Pictures, Calendar, Links, email addresses
- Formatting and spell checking available
- Export the journal to PDF, HTML, Latex or plain text
- Zip backup

[image: ScreenShot1]

Answer (score 2):

[Org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) is a great text-based todo list manager with checkboxes and timestamps. It is:

- Cross platform (Runs on Emacs and [other environments](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tools/index.html))
- Free and open source
- Has an agenda mode with reminders

You can read more about it in the [compact guide](http://orgmode.org/orgguide.pdf). Here's an example from the main website:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something that is web based.

So as long as you are online, and browsing (which is something most of us do naturally without fail), it would be up there in your browser.

This is what I use:

- The app/software - Any.Do
- Browsers - Firefox/Chrome
- Platforms - Any PC platform with browser would do, PLUS, Android and ios devices.

The benefits are as follows:

1. Any.Do is one of the leading software/apps for to-do lists and reminders.
2. It is integrated with Cal (another calendar application by the same people) and Google Calendar, as well as Gmail. Integrations are extremely functional and powerful.
3. In browsers these days, you can make your own accounts with settings and extensions and so on. So if you download Any.Do extension in your browser account, you can basically have the same setup along browsers on both systems.
4. Since this works on mobile devices as well, not only would it give you reminders in your browser/email integration but will also give you notifications via your mobile device.

The implementation and setting up is a one time step and after that I am pretty sure your to-do lists and tasks can be managed easily.

Best of all, its FREE! :)

Comment: "Free" as in "free beer", you pay with your privacy. But nice and detailed answer, +1 from me :)